# ¿Cómo podría realizar un percentil especifico (por ejemplo 0.85) a una variable compuesta por 10 rangos?

Tags: r, percentil

¿Cómo podría crear una variable compuesta del percentil especifico (por ejemplo 0.85) correspondiente a una variable compuesta por 10 rangos?

Tengo una variable que es edad con 10 rangos de edades.
Y querría obtener sobrepeso, usando el percentil 85 de una variable (peso),
para obtener finalmente una tabla que muestre en la primera columna la edad por rangos y a continuación otra columna que muestre el percentil 85 del peso en cada rango de edad.

Comment: Bienvenido user113067 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de esta variable compuesta que mencionas y  que resultado esperas obtener con un percentil de 0.85?

Answer (score 0):

De lo que comentas, interpreto lo siguiente:

1. Tienes una estructura de datos, digamos un `data.frame` dónde tienes una edad y un peso. Algo como esto:

   ```
   set.seed(2019)
   pesos <- data.frame(edad = sample(9:85, 200, replace=TRUE),
                       peso = sample(20:200, 200, replace=TRUE))

   head(pesos)

     edad peso
   1   68   56
   2   63  135
   3   32  165
   4   56  189
   5   12   64
   6   12  172
   ```
2. Por otro lado manejas rangos de edades, por ejemplo, teniendo un vector con los "cortes" de cada rango. Por ejemplo

   ```
   edades <- seq(0,100,20)
   edades

   [1]   0  20  40  60  80 100
   ```

   En este caso serían 5 intervalos de 0 a 100 años en pasos de 20 años, el primero de 1 a 20, el segundo de 21 a 40, etc.

Ahora, lo que buscas es obtener el valor de peso del percentilo 85 pero para cada rango. Para esto, en primer lugar deberemos definir a cada observación el rango que le corresponde, para esto usaremos `cut()`:

```
pesos$rango_edad <- cut(pesos$edad, edades, ordered_result=TRUE)
head(pesos)

  edad peso rango_edad
1   68   56    (60,80]
2   63  135    (60,80]
3   32  165    (20,40]
4   56  189    (40,60]
5   12   64     (0,20]
6   12  172     (0,20]
```

En `rango_edad` tenemos el rango al que pertenecería cada peso, la notación `(a,b]` de cada etiqueta significa que el rango va de `a+1` a `b` inclusive. Por último para obtener el percentilo buscado, deberemos agrupar los datos por este rango y calcular sobre los datos de cada grupo:

```
aggregate(peso ~ rango_edad, data=pesos, FUN=function(x) {quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, length = 101))[86]})

  rango_edad   peso
1     (0,20] 159.25
2    (20,40] 163.80
3    (40,60] 170.90
4    (60,80] 177.30
5   (80,100] 142.50
```

Si quieres agregar más de una función sumaria, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
aggregate(peso ~ rango_edad, 
          data=pesos, 
          FUN=function(x) {
              c(quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, length = 101))[86],
                quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, length = 101))[96])
              })

  rango_edad peso.85% peso.95%
1     (0,20]   159.25   180.50
2    (20,40]   163.80   188.80
3    (40,60]   170.90   182.20
4    (60,80]   177.30   193.40
5   (80,100]   142.50   150.50
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es lo que estaba intentando hacer, pero me ha surgido otro problema, ¿cómo podria poner en esta fórmula: "aggregate(peso ~ rango_edad, data=pesos, FUN=function(x) {quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, length = 101))[86]})" , dos percentiles? es decir añadir también el percentil 95

Comment: @user113067, edité mi pregunta para explicar tú último comentario. Saludos.